# Primary key generation from another table column using EF core

Tags: database, entity-framework, .net-core, configuration, fluent

[image]

EF core configuration

I need to configure the Id of Class B as the primary key which is the column of Class A. Is this possible in EF core?

Comment: Show us the code sample please so it will be easy to give a solution for what need to be donne on how you designed the two entites.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Sorry I don't have code sample. Above picture has sample relationship.

Comment: So on your side, could you please give the minimum sample C# ?